# UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController freezes my app

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, swift2

At some point in my app I need to go back to my main (i.e. home) ViewController. So I need to travel backwards into my navigation stack which by now is full with ViewControllers and NavigationControllers. So I do the following:

```
// to dismiss the current VC
self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

// to go back home
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController = homeNC
```

homeNC is a global var pointing to a NavigationController containing a storyboard instance of my main "home" ViewController.

It works, but partially. Meaning, it does take me back to my home ViewController but it then becomes unresponsive to touches and scrolling. Nothing responds, neither the navigationBar buttons nor the TableViewCells inside the home NC/VC. Xcode doesn't crash, just sits there waiting.

I can't figure out why. Can anyone think what I'm missing here?

** **EDIT** **

Maybe it's because I am embedding a nested VC inside my main (home) VC. Here's the code and what else I tried since:

```
homeNC = self.navigationController!
homeVC = self

let discoverVC: UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DiscoverVC") as UIViewController

// embed discoverVC in this VC
self.addChildViewController(discoverVC)
self.view.addSubview(discoverVC.view)
discoverVC.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

// store self NC for using it by "thank you" VC to come back to home after payment
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

// navigates back but becomes unresponsive
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = homeVC

// navigates back but becomes unresponsive
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = homeNC
```

I also tried saving a reference to the appdelegate window with the following:

```
// Initialise sideMenu
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

let sideMenu = SSASideMenu(contentViewController: UINavigationController(rootViewController: MainViewController()), leftMenuViewController: LeftMenuViewController())

window!.rootViewController = sideMenu
window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

// get a reference to appdelegate's window so that we can navigate back later
mainWindow = window!
```

but again it doesn't navigate back when I do:

```
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = mainWindow.rootViewController
```

Comment: Use Xcode to pause the app and see what's happening on the main thread during the freeze.

Comment: Hmm at some point during the transition one of the logs says "Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged". I am on iOS8 by the way

Comment: Like I said, check the stack trace.  It's usually better than guessing.  :)

Comment: Why are you dismissing a controller with animation if you are removing the whole hierarchy at the same time?

Comment: It still wouldn't fix this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I will work for you.

```
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = mainVC
```

**EDIT**

I read out your edited question. Problem is occurring due to `SSASideMenu`. I updated my answer and I hope now it will work for you. You have to make two changes. First in `AppDelegate.swift`, make property of `SSASideMenu` like this:

```
var window: UIWindow?
var sideMenu: SSASideMenu!
```

Now your code will be changed to:

```
sideMenu = SSASideMenu(contentViewController: UINavigationController(rootViewController: MainViewController()), leftMenuViewController: LeftMenuViewController())
```

Now if you want to change the view-controller, you have to change the `contentViewController` of `SSASideMenu` like this:

```
func showDiscoverVC() {
    //Instantiate ViewController
    let discoverVC: UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DiscoverVC") as UIViewController

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.sideMenu.contentViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: discoverVC)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately it's the same behaviour; Goes back to homeVC but remains unresponsive.

Comment: @Polis: Please remove:
self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
and call the method that I shared with you.

Comment: Still unresponsive I am afraid.

Comment: @Polis: Can you share the code for homeNC var initialization?

Comment: Just did along with examples of subsequent attempts.

Comment: @Polis: I edited my answer after reading your edited question. I hope now it will work for you.

Comment: It still didn't accomplish 100% of what I needed but your suggestion took away the freezing bit and helped me reshape my logic, so I am accepting your answer, thanks.